# Android scoped storage - how to customize directory picker

Tags: android, kotlin, scoped-storage

I prompt user to pick a directory for my app to use with this intent:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
        intent.addFlags(
               Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                    or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
                    or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
        )
startActivityForResult(intent, DIR_ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE)
```

It works OK, but the user gets this really unclear prompt as in the picture.

Is it possible to customize it somehow, or at least show the devices storage instead of this "recent" thing?

[image: this prompt]

Comment: `intent.addFlags()` Please remove that statement. You cannot grand anything. You should be glad if you are granted access to the directory the user picks.

Comment: It seems that hose flags do nothing, i'll remove them. But still this does not help to customize the directory picker.

Comment: Of course not. It was no answer. It was a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Use the StorageManager to give you a list of the available StorageVolume's.

There is primary storage volume and one for the micro sd card if inserted.

Once you have a volume you can obtain a launch intent for it.

If you start that intent the picker will open displaying that volume.

Comment: Thanks, ill try this

Comment: Think this is only for Q+. Please try.

Comment: Works fine, but for Q+ only. Unfortunately, i need smth for API 21+